# Form data comes through as unicode instead of string

Tags: python, django, unicode

I am trying to post some data to my view using a handmade form (rather than using a Django one) but it is not coming through as expected. Here is what the data looks like from the request:
http://grab.by/K7ay

And this is the code that I use to retrieve/display it.

`print(request.POST)
print("slot_range: %s"%type(request.POST.get('slot_range')))`

I am expecting a string, or an array, but as you can see, slot_range is coming through as 'unicode' and when I try to split it or get the first element, it doesn't work.

Using Django forms doesn't seem to have this issue.

I am also tried setting the enctype to multipart/formdata ad that doesn't help.

What's causing this and what can I do to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright this is embarrassing... Literally just solved my issue.

The solution was to store the variable first, then split it.